# cannot stop assetWriter finishWriting

Tags: video, crash, save, screen-capture, avassetwriter

I am trying to do screen capturing and write as video file.

```
assetWriterTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                    target:self
                                                  selector:@selector (writeSample:)
                                                  userInfo:nil
                                                   repeats:YES] ;

-(void) writeSample: (NSTimer*) _timer
{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
           //capture and save image to video
        });
}
```

To stop recording, I write

```
-(void) stopRecording 
{

[assetWriterTimer invalidate];
assetWriterTimer = nil;
[assetWriterTimer release];

[assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^(){
    NSLog (@"finished writing completion handler");
}];

NSLog (@"finished writing");
}
```

However, I mostly get this error and application crash. How should I do? 
-[AVAssetWriter finishWriting] Cannot call method when status is 2'

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling [assetWriter startWriting] somewhere?

This error basically means that the writer isn't really writing now, so it can't really stop writing. If you did look at what the [AVWriter's status codes](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AVAssetWriterStatus) mean, you would see that 2 is for when it's completed writing.

```
enum {
 AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown = 0,
 AVAssetWriterStatusWriting,
 AVAssetWriterStatusCompleted,
 AVAssetWriterStatusFailed,
 AVAssetWriterStatusCancelled
};
```

Comment: Your answer is brilliant. It is a sham that Apple hired satan to write their documentation and create their APIs and development tools. `AVAssetWriterStatusUnknown` means not just what you say but also anything related to `AVAssetWriter` that is related to writing to a file, that is not initialized. The idea is this: how can we finish writing if we are not even writing? The API is so poorly documented and conceived that this should not be a reason for crash, but rather, for a warning inside the finish handler, but satan runs the show inside Apple, so, it is a crash and there is no soup for you